# Microsoft Azure Load Balancer Testing

Tags: azure

I have created an Internet-facing load balancer using the Azure Portal.

Can someone let me know if there is a way to test it?

Cheers

Carlton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If you already haven't, put two VMs behind the load balancer.
- Create a load balancing rule for a service running on the VMs (f.e. TCP 80 for HTTP).
- Verify you can connect to the load balancer's IP address on the published port; you should end up connecting to one of the VMs.
- Turn off VM 1 and verify the service is still accessible on VM 2.
- Repeat the same test by turning on VM 2 and turning off VM 1.
- Optional: if you are using IP affinity, turn on both VMs and verify you end up actually reaching the same VM when connecting several times to the load balancer from the same IP address.

(The question might be quite silly, but it's actually important to test load balancers when placing them in front of important services, and to make sure they actually do what they should.)

Comment: thanks for responding. I created the my Load Balancer load balancer environment based on https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-get-started-internet-portal/

Comment: Massimo, can you let me know how to connect to the load baancers IP address? How do I verify the service is still accessible on VM 2.

Comment: Hello all, I'm trying to test my loadbalancer functionality.I understand that Azure load balancer won't allow ICMP, however when I attempt to test with psping https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/jj729731.aspx Load balancer wont respond. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hello all, just to you know I've also used nmap to try and connect to the Load balancer

Comment: you mentioned 'Verify you can connect to the load balancer's IP address on the published port'. Can you let me know how I do just that? Cheers